Delete Company and User in Magento B2B Graphql
Is there a way to delete a company and its user using only user authentication in Magento 2 B2B? For example, if a B2B user tries to delete their account, the associated company should also be deleted. Can this be achieved via a GraphQL mutation like this?
mutation {
   deleteCompanyByUser {
     success
     message
   }
}

